# fulltext search plugins for thunderbird?

Tags: email, search, productivity

i like to search my mails very fast. i tried xobni but i dislike outlook, i tried postbox (a tbird on stereoids) but i dislike the price. are there any other fulltext search engines for thunderbird?

(i access my mails via imap, so google-desktop would have a hard time to catch my mails)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as it seems, the new thunderbird3 will have full text search *built in*: **GLODA**

> Mozilla Messaging has announced the availability of new Thunderbird 3 beta release. This version introduces an impressive new search feature with a timeline visualization and powerful interactive filtering support. 
>   [quote](http://arstechnica.com/open-source/reviews/2009/09/hands-on-thunderbird-3-beta-4-hatches-with-improved-search.ars)

about GLODA: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Thunderbird/About_gloda

enabling GLODA: https://wiki.mozilla.org/Thunderbird:Using_Gloda

Answer (score 1):

See the [simile-seek](http://code.google.com/p/simile-seek/) add-on, advertised as :

> Thunderbird extension for more effective email browsing and searching

I never used it, so can't say how good it is from personal experience.

Comment: looks interesting, Thanks for sharing

Comment: download link -> http://code.google.com/p/simile-seek/source/browse/seek/trunk/seek-1.0.2.xpi

Comment: looks nice, but it needs more work on the full-indexing and the ui. it doesnt index all the mail and then stores that indexing to disk but the user has to reindex the (sub)folders each time one wants to search.